# How to embed razor variable in string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine

I'd like to add a razor model variable into a resource file string.  I've tried the following but the variable is rendered as a literal:

attempt 1:

```
"There is a variable @Model.here"
```

attempt 2:

```
"There is a variable @(Model.here)"
```

In the code, it is referenced like this:

```
@MyManager.GetString("resourcefilevariable")
```

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: My first thought on this is, it's not a good idea.  What you're saying is, that this resource string is tightly bound to razor only and cannot be used anywhere else.  Additionally, it's now tightly bound to a run-time variable, meaning that it can only be debugged at run-time which can be very dangerous.

Comment: It's huge difference where you place your code.if you are inside Razor block (between `@{` and `}`) then another `@` is simply a syntactic error because you are already inside Razor. Then you need to use string.Format to format your string. On the other hand, if you inside HTML tag, `@(variable)` will work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is better to do this kind of thing by storing

```
"There is a variable {0}"
```

as the resource string, and in the view, writing something like this:

```
@string.Format(Resources.String, model.here);
```

As a full example:

Here is the model class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Foo()
    {
        Name = "bar";
    }
}
```

It has controller with a simple Index ActionResult:

```
    // GET: Foo
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new Foo());
    }
```

There is a resx file with resource

```
[resourceName, <strong>name of model is: {0}</strong>]
```

In the razor view, render this as

```
@Html.Raw(string.Format(Resources.resourceName, Model.Name))
```

Comment: I don't think that will work since the resource file variable isn't being referenced.  I've updated the OP with that detail.

Comment: So writing `@string.Format(MyManager.GetString("resourcefilevariable"), model.here);` would not do the job?

Comment: That does work.  I have some HTML in this resource file string (<strong> tag).  It is coming through as a literal.  Is there a way to make it render?

Answer (score 1):

As Leigh Shepperson pointed out, you can use a string with placeholders and `string.Format` to replace placeholders with actual values. If the string contains any HTML tags it should be rendered with `Html.Raw` method.

```
@Html.Raw(string.Format(Resources.String, model.here))
```